# MS Access: "Not In" is not working correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

**MS ACCESS SQL**

```
DELETE * 
FROM Lane_Details
WHERE Lane_Details.Week not in(SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 Lane_Details.Week
           FROM Lane_Details
WHERE Lane_Details.Week IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Week DESC; )
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

What I need this to do is delete anything out of the table that is 4 weeks old or older.

I have been having trouble with the not in. it cause Access to completely lock up. I am not sure what the correct syntax should be for this, and I know that I can write it with a left outer join but I don't know how to do that.

**DATA**

```
ID            Lane  Time                        Week
6213214 83198524    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201315
6213183 61780698    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201311
6213201 11145552    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201315
6213202 82391025    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201314
6213203 11149012    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201311
6213204 11140048    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201311
6213205 83198524    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201316
6213207 61625652    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201316
6213210 61625652    4/6/2012 12:31:00 AM    201311
6637195 36166433    5/1/2012 8:25:00 AM           201314
6637206 77222091    5/1/2012 10:50:00 AM    201314
```

With this data, I would want to delete any row that has Week 201311. I want to keep 201314, 201315, and 201316.

The subquery will run on this table, and grab the top 3 dates (14, 15, 16) in this case. I then say "not in" to delete all the 11's.

Comment: remove the semicolon inside the subquery

Comment: what is the problem?  are wrong rows deleted?  is there an error message? which one?

Comment: @LuisSiquot There is no error messages, and no rows are being deleted. My CPU begs, almost like it is doing some very intensive query that causes the PC to work overtime. I have to kill the Access process to even use Access again

Comment: what data type *week* has?  please attach some example rows.  how many rows has the table?

Comment: @LuisSiquot I just added some data into the description. Let me know if you understand a little better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help. I finally realized that it wasn't my query, it just ran really slow. I think it was a performance issue. I decided to break the query down into a few different ones. It is working much better now. i eventually found [this](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html) website and came to that conclusion.

VBA isnt the best place to do sub queries.

Comment: This was just my inexperience. I was able to do it much more efficently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well Access handles a self-reference in the WHERE clause on deleting.  But you could do something like this instead to avoid the subquery:

```
DELETE FROM Lane_Details
WHERE Week <= (THIS WEEK - 4 WEEKS)
```

Where "THIS WEEK - 4 WEEKS" is a relevant expression to represent the end date before which you want to delete rows.

Comment: Would that still work if Week was 201315? Year and week? my experience would say no, but that isn't saying much.

Comment: Yes it would, but obviously it would help to know what week stores first.  You haven't told us that.

Comment: the way I have it coded, the first week would be the most recent, then go back 2 weeks

Comment: this is like an automated purge

Answer (score 0):

> What I need this to do is delete anything out of the table that is 4 weeks old or older.

Can you not do something like :-

```
DELETE * FROM Lane_Details where Week<=datepart("yyyy",dateadd("w",-4,now())) & datepart("ww",dateadd("w",-4,now()))
```

You may need to convert Week to a string but that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the semicolon inside the subquery and create an index on week field.  the query should work fine.